# Laravel Collective Remote | Is it possible to get live output?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, ssh, laravelcollective

I currently have everything setup and ready to do remote commands using ssh onto all of the servers in my database but I would like to display the live output to the user of the commands that are ran, I have seen this done before like on TinyCP and some other VPS Control Panels but I wasnt sure if the Laravel Collective Remote package could do it.

## What I have tried

I have tried a few things to accomplish this, one of them is doing the php logic in a blade file and just including it when I needed like shown below.

```
<div>
<?php
    try {
        $server = \App\Models\Server::first();
        config([
            'remote.connections.remote-server.host'     =>
$server['hostname'],
            'remote.connections.remote-server.username' => $server['user'],
            'remote.connections.remote-server.password' => $server['password'],
        ]);
        $commands = array(
            "apt-get update",
        );
        \SSH::into('remote-server')->
run($commands, function ($line) {
            echo nl2br($line);
        });
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo($e);
    }
?>
```

I thought this would accomplish what I wanted because I was under the impression that the function would activate per line almost on a loop but it waits until its fully done to output the lines. The output I got is shown below.

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Fetched 252 kB in 1s (170 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
```

## Example of the output I want

What I am going for is to have output to where I can format to look like a terminal either  through custom css or by using  [xterm.js](https://xtermjs.org).

Xterm.js's example of a terminal
[image: Xterm.js's example of a terminal]

Comment: Output is buffered until completion. You can force a flush with either `ob_flush()` or `flush()`. Although browsers now have an all or none buffering strategy

Comment: Doing this still gave the same result, it just outputs everything at once after all of the commands are done running. Although I did not know ob_flush() existed and that could be super useful while messing with this.

Comment: Yea I know, most modern browsers implement a no buffering strategy nowadays

Comment: If you want to stream it live to the browser you'll probably have to use websockets or some form of polling

Comment: Yeah true, I was looking into maybe using Socket.io but not 100% yet.